# How to get number and names of columns that have at least one null value

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to filter out columns that have at least one missing value after getting the number of the columns and thier names.
I use this function to get the names and number of columns that contain only missing values, than I filter them out of the data frame:

```
CheckColAllNulls <- if (ncol(Filter(function(x) all(is.na(x)), df)) > 0) {
  cat("columns have only nulls:",ncol(Filter( function(x) all(is.na(x)), df)))
  cat("columns names that have only nulls:",colnames(Filter( function(x) all(is.na(x)), df)))
  df <- Filter(function(x) ! all(is.na(x)), df)
  print("columns having only nulls removed ")
} else {
  print("No columns having only nulls are found")
}
```

I tried to do the same operation but for columns that have at least one missing value by using `colSums` but with out success.

```
CheckColNulls <- if ( colSums(is.na(df)) > 0) {
  cat("columns have more than one null:",ncol(colSums(is.na(df)) > 0 ))
  cat("columns names that have more than one null:",colnames(colSums(is.na(df)) > 0 ))
  df <- Filter(function(x)  colSums(is.na(x)) > 0), df)
  print("columns having at least one null removed ")
} else {
  print("No columns having at least one null are found")
}
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
Error in colSums(is.na(x)) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In if (colSums(is.na(df)) > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Please be more precise in your language. `NA` is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: The warning can reproduced by `if (c(3,7) > 0) print("hello")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using `any(is.na(x))`:

```
CheckColAllNulls <- if (ncol(Filter(function(x) any(is.na(x)), df)) > 0) {
    cat("columns have only nulls:",ncol(Filter( function(x) any(is.na(x)), df)))
    cat("\n\n")
    cat("columns names that have only nulls:",colnames(Filter( function(x) any(is.na(x)), df)))
    cat("\n\n")
    df <- Filter(function(x) ! any(is.na(x)), df)
     print("columns having any nulls are removed")
} else {
    print("No columns having any nulls are found")
}
```